# How can I open a photo in mail that is missing it's extension?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, photos

My security camera sends jpgs that are missing the filename extension ".jpg" Is there any way to view these images on my iPhone?

Answer (score -1):

One way is try to "rename it" add .jpg If the file is not corrupted it will work.